# Keras dense model gradient explosion

Tags: optimization, keras, gradient

I have a very simple dense layer model takes 10 input values, 20 units in hidden layer, 1 unit in output layer, and "relu" as activation function, adam optimizer with learning rate 0.01

```
densemodel=keras_model_sequential();
layer_dense(densemodel, input_shape=ncol(trainingX), units=20, activation="relu")       
layer_dropout(densemodel, rate=0.1)
layer_dense(densemodel, units=1, activation="relu")

optimizer=optimizer_adam(lr=0.01,clipnorm=1);
compile(densemodel, optimizer=optimizer, loss="logcosh", metrics = list("mean_squared_error"))
```

I trained the model with n = 2e4 training data and ran into serious gradient explosion, which was finally confirmed caused by some outliers (n < 10) in the training records.

Without removing the the outlier records, any one or combination of the following strategies failed to address the gradient explosion problem.

kernel_regularizer, bias_regularizer, activity_regularizer, clipnorm=1, clipvalue=0.5 or 0.1, set learning rate to 1e-5, add drop out layer, increase batch size.
basically none of them work.
I expect at least clipnorm or clipvalue should work since according to definition

```
clipnorm: Gradients will be clipped when their L2 norm exceeds this
          value.

clipvalue: Gradients will be clipped when their absolute value exceeds
          this value.
```

but why they failed?

Comment: What exactly is `n` here? And why do you believe `clipvalue` `clipnorm` don't work?

Comment: n is the number of training data. E.g. when n is 2e4, then the training data is a 2e4 by 10 matrix. Each row is a training record.  Set clipnorm to 1 or/and clipvalue to 0.5 (or less) does not address the gradient explosion problem

Comment: Are you sure its gradient explosion? What evidence do you have? Did you normalize the input data?

Comment: Yes, the input data (i.e. x) are strictly normalized to between 0 and 1. The training target (i.e. y) (which in this case has only 1 dimension) could be > 1 or < 0, but should generally be between -3 and +3 to make sense. In practice there might be very few outliers with target greater than 100 or even 1000, which cause MSE (the metrics) to suddenly jump to > 1e5 from, say, 0.35.

Comment: Since the input data are strictly >0  and <1, I can't imagine any explanations other than gradient explosion that can cause MSE to hike to  1e5 or more. Correct me if I am wrong.